# Referencing scope children in filters (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I'm an AngularJS newbie, and am putting together a pretty basic proof-of-concept for my boss. It's listings for car hire, with a results list in the main area of the view populated via some external JSON, and a filters panel down the side. You can see the Plunker I've created here:

http://plnkr.co/lNJNYagMC2rszbSOF95k

I've been able to successfully reference child objects/values in my ngRepeat:

```
  <article data-ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search" class="result">
    <h3>{{result.carType.name}}, {{result.carDetails.doors}} door, &pound;{{result.price.value}} - {{ result.company.name }}</h3>
    <ul class="result-features">
        <li>{{result.carDetails.hireDuration}} day hire</li>
        <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.airCon">Air conditioning</li>
        <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.unlimitedMileage">Unlimited Mileage</li>
        <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.theftProtection">Theft Protection</li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

...however, I've so far been unable to access the 2nd level child objects in my search filter. So, for example, where I'm filtering by 'car type' (see below), I'd like to be able to use 'search.carType.name' as my ngModel, to be as specific as possible - but this doesn't work, although just using 'search.carType' works fine. Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<h4>Car type:</h4>
    Compact <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="search.carType" ng-true-value="Compact" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Intermediate <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="search.carType" ng-true-value="Intermediate" ng-false-value="" /><br>
    Premium <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="search.carType" ng-true-value="Premium" ng-false-value="" /><br>
```

Comment: you should be using filter:search.carType.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your search object is being populated correctly, but filter isn't consuming it in the way you expect. Looking at the implementation of filter (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js), it appears to only go one layer of child-properties deep when it is given an object as a filter definition.

Ajay's suggestion will work, but you would then need to chain additional filters to accomodate your other parameters. You could change both car type and company to specify x.name in the ng-model and then alter the filter to  `filter:search.carType.name|filter:search.company.name`.  If you were only going to have a small number of parameter types, I'd handle it this way.

On the other hand, the nice thing about your current approach is that it's transparent. There's no need to the filter call to be changed if the number of parameters changes elsewhere. If you might have a relatively large number of those, or if they were dynamic, I would take a more scalable approach. Write a filter FUNCTION that consumes the search object, and goes more than one level deep in comparing the children to the filtered data.

Comment: You don't actually need a whole custom filter, I think. You can use the 'function' option for the filter Filter (think we're overusing that word a bit?) Look here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter. You don't need to mutate the set you're filtering, just give a true or false for each item, and filter will do that out of the box. You just need to give it a comparator function which uses your search object to evaluate each item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice post by  Anton Kropp on deep object filtering: [FILTER ON DEEP OBJECT PROPERTIES IN ANGULARJS](http://onoffswitch.net/filter-deep-object-properties-angularjs/)

The relevant code:

```
function initFilters(app){
    app.filter('property', property);
}

function property(){
    function parseString(input){
        return input.split(".");
    }

    function getValue(element, propertyArray){
        var value = element;

        _.forEach(propertyArray, function(property){
            value = value[property];
        });

        return value;
    }

    return function (array, propertyString, target){
        var properties = parseString(propertyString);

        return _.filter(array, function(item){
            return getValue(item, properties) == target;
        });
    }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<ul>
    only failed: <input type="checkbox"
                  ng-model="onlyFailed"
                  ng-init="onlyFailed=false"/>

    <li ng-repeat="entry in data.entries | property:'test.status.pass':!onlyFailed">
        <test-entry test="entry.test"></test-entry>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MbeR5/1/)